# Change/Rename the ReservedIPName of AzureReservedIP

Tags: powershell, azure

Is it possible to change the ReservedIPName of an already created AzureReservedIP?

Thanks,
Kate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  You will have to create a new one using the new name and associate it with your cloud service.